# How to use showTimePicker as Widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, datetimepicker

I want the user to pick the date and time, for that there is date time picker dialogue.

But, is there a way that, I could show the date-time persistently on some flutter widget and use like any other widget?

```
Container(
   child: showTimePicker(
          context: context,
          initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
            return Theme(
              data: ThemeData.dark(),
              child: child,
            );
          },
        );
}
```

but I cannot use `showTimePicker` as Widget.

How to use `showTimePicker()` as widget? so that other widgets can be built on top of it.

Comment: your question seems to bit unclear. can you share the code what you have tried till now, and if any issues you have faced till now. there are libraries present regarding the date time picker you can check the out.

Comment: I just want to use the showTimePicker not as dialogue but as a widget, so that I can build on top of that and make custom widget.?

Comment: everything in flutter is a widget. so would like you to be precise about the behavior of date time picker you are looking for and if it's not present in public libraries you would probably need to build it out yourself or get some help.

Comment: `showTimePicker` is a dialogue that displays the `TimePicker` widget, right?.  I want to use that `TimePicker`  in my Own Widget. hope you got my problem now.

Comment: yeah I think I get what you are looking for that's why I replied you will need to build out your own library if you are looking for custom functionality / ui regarding date time picker and for that you'll need to first define what you are looking for and how It will look and work

Comment: It would be very easy to build my own widget because I will reuse the `showTimePicker`. `TimePicker` is a complex widget and currently, it's out of my scope. I want to use `showTimePicker()` as widget.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the problem just like you some time ago and I copied the source code and made my custom widget. Now, it can be used like any widget. If you want to adopt this, I want to mention a couple of things.

1. I am not sure if this works well with localization, I did not test that.
2. I am not sure if this works on other themes than the light theme, I only tested on the light theme.

You can find the code here.
https://gist.github.com/mithunadhikari40/b55b9990ebc15d0d8bf70fd3f87709b0

Usage:
Copy the code from the above link, create a dart file, paste the code and use it like this:

```
                     SizedBox(
                        child: TimePickerDialog(
                        initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.now()),
                        onTimeChange: (TimeOfDay time) {
                          print(
                              "What we get the value of the time is now $time");
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to open `showTimePicker` on click of any widget. So you can simply put your code of `showTimePicker` inside onTap property of the `GestureDetector` as shown below.

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () async {
        TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
        initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
           return MediaQuery(
           data: MediaQuery.of(context)
           .copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
           child: child,
           );
        },);
     },
     child: Text("SetTime",textAlign: TextAlign.center,));
```