# Correct Flutter's showTimePicker Format (Flutter Web)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to use Flutter's `showTimePicker` in a Web app, but the format of the displayed widget is awful (see below).

[image]

The numbers are not visible, nor is the clock line and circle over the selected number, or even the ok/cancel buttons.

(My App is 100% web, so I haven't tested it on a smartphone)

The code of my implementation is quite simple (I adapted it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61593827/12384807) post):

```dart
class myWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.edit),
          onPressed: () async {
              TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
                context: context,
                initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                  return MediaQuery(
                  data: MediaQuery.of(context)
                  .copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: false),
                  child: child,
                  );
                },);
          },);
  }
}
```

I am guessing there might be something wrong with my `theme`, which I created more or less like this:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    errorColor: Colors.red, //Color
    // ...
  );
  //...
)
```

Note that I only changed a few values from `ThemeData` -where needed-.

Any ideas of what might be going on?

Thanks

Comment: Flutter for web is in beta. I am not surprised. Have you built and hosted your web app or testing it with flutter run ? If built, which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS Code, and running it through Run/Start Debugging. I think it is equivalent to Flutter run. It runs on Chrome.

Comment: Try in a Stateful widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, the solution was on the Theme settings. I changed the following two important items:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    //First change: Give a Color to the Ok/Cancel buttons' text.
    //(In this case, red)
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(style: ButtonStyle(foregroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.red),)),
    //Second change:
    //Give colors to hour/minute inputs and dial hand:
    timePickerTheme: _myTimePickerTheme(ThemeData().timePickerTheme),
  );
  //...
)
```

Where, the function `_myTimePickerTheme` is as follows:

```dart
TimePickerThemeData _myTimePickerTheme (TimePickerThemeData base){
    
    Color myTimePickerMaterialStateColorFunc(Set<MaterialState> states, {bool withBackgroundColor = false}) {
    const Set<MaterialState> interactiveStates = <MaterialState>{
      MaterialState.pressed,
      MaterialState.hovered,
      MaterialState.focused,
      MaterialState.selected, //This is the one actually used
    };
    if (states.any(interactiveStates.contains)) {
      // the color to return when button is in pressed, hovered, focused, or selected state
      return Colors.red.withOpacity(0.12);
    }
    // the color to return when button is in it's normal/unfocused state 
    return withBackgroundColor ? Colors.grey[200] : Colors.transparent;
  }

    return base.copyWith(
      hourMinuteTextColor: Colors.red,
      hourMinuteColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) => myTimePickerMaterialStateColorFunc(states, withBackgroundColor: true)), //Background of Hours/Minute input
      dayPeriodTextColor: Colors.red,
      dayPeriodColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(myTimePickerMaterialStateColorFunc), //Background of AM/PM.
      dialHandColor: Colors.red,
    );
  }
```

The result is displayed below:
[image: TimePicker with colors]

**Note:** If you don't want to change the TextButton Theme of your entire app, you can wrap the child of `showTimePicker`'s builder, in a `Theme` widget, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56465#issuecomment-670500038).